# iText digital signature using javax.smartcardio

Tags: itext, smartcard

I'm trying to sign a pdf with belgian eId smart Card. I've installed Eclipse, downloaded Java SDK 1.6, added the itext 5.4.5 jars smardcardsign-1.0 jars as external jars to the building path.

I want to test example "4.6 signing a string for authentication" from Bruno's whitepaper "Digital Signature for PDF documents".

I copied C4_05_SignWithBEID.java file from itext download site.

I've got an error "AUTHN_CERT_FILE_ID can not be resolved or is not a field"
for line X509Certificate cert = card.readCertificate(BeIDCertificates.AUTHN_CERT_FILE_ID);

When I check the properties for class BeIdCertificates the "AUTHN_CERT_FILE_ID" is not available.

Has someone a complete source for the example 4.8 signing a document using the EidSignature class ?

Answer (score 2):

Please don't copy/paste from examples I have written without reading the accompanying book, in this case the free eBook ["Digital Signatures for PDF documents"](http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures).

The example you mention is taken from section 4.2.2 from that book, entitled "Extracting data from the Belgian eID using smartcardsign."

Allow me to quote myself (page 105):

> We can use the `javax.smartcardio` API to access any smart card, but
>   unfortunately it's usually not that simple. Every card has its own
>   file structure, its own applications, its own data definitions, and so
>   on. Apart from the ISO/IEC specification, you'll always need the
>   specifications of the card you want to use. I've written a small
>   library that wraps the generic Java API classes in objects such as
>   `CardReaders`, `SmartCard` and `SmartCardWithKey`. I wrote a special
>   class for the Belgian eID, named `BeIDCard`. You can find this library
>   on [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/smartcardsign/). It’s meant as a light-weight library that
>   supports only the basic functionality.

You can find the link to that library in the footnotes: http://sourceforge.net/projects/smartcardsign/

The class `BeIDCertificates` is part of this library, and it has a constant named `AUTHN_CERT_FILE_ID`.